# Is it possible to name something in XAML without getting a field for that object?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I use `x:Name` to name an element in XAML because I want to be able to reference it using `Storyboard.TargetName` but everything that has `x:Name` set also gets a field generated in the code-behind. Is it possible to target an element with `Storyboard.TargetName` without getting a field (which FxCop gives a warning about unused private code for).

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't it be more reasonable to just [suppress the FxCop warning](http://bloggingabout.net/blogs/jschreuder/archive/2006/06/08/12400.aspx)? This is obviously a false positive since it's generated code.

Edit: actually, what you need is [a project suppression file](http://www.binarycoder.net/fxcop/html/tutorial.html) (search for "SupressMessages.cs")

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, thats what I'm doing now. But I just wanted to check if there was another way as I don't need the generated field.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it helps if you set Visibility="Hidden", so it's not there but you can use it.

Comment: His problem is that the private variable exists, not that it's visible in the window/control/whatever. Besides, if you want to actually hide something, you should use Collapsed so that it's not taken into account when measuring the layout.